# Is there a way to delay execution in CLIPS

Tags: clips

I'm writing a clips code that goes through for loop , and it print facts .
I wanna know if there is a way to delay execution for 10 seconds , after printing the first fact , then another 10 second at the second iteration ?
so is there a delay function like java?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built-in that allows you to sleep the CLIPS process for a fix amount of time, but you can write a function which loops for a specified amount of time before returning:

```
CLIPS> 
(deffunction pause (?delay)
   (bind ?start (time))
   (while (< (time) (+ ?start ?delay)) do))
CLIPS> (pause 5)
FALSE
CLIPS>
```